# Scrolling button android

Tags: android, android-button, android-scrollview, android-scroll

All 
I want button like below image.  An button is scrollable and get the selected digit as like in image currently 0 is selected. Any one have an idea?

[image]

Comment: you can use horizontal scroll view..

Comment: in scroll view i can add view in it but how can i get selected digit? can you add some sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used below code for implement it.

https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel

Thanks
Girish